# Calculate position within gradient color

Tags: javascript

I'm new here. It's a very hard question, at least for me :)

I'm creating my own color picker. There are two convas, one for the board and one for the slider.

Both of them are drawn by JavaScript so that I can use `getImageData` to get the color of the pixel.

For example, the color slider is as below:

```js
const colorRange = document.querySelector ( '#firstColorSlider' ),
   drawColorRef = colorRange.getContext ( '2d' ),
   gradientC = drawColorRef.createLinearGradient ( 0, 0, drawColorRef.canvas.width, 0 );

gradientC.addColorStop ( 0, '#f00' );
gradientC.addColorStop ( 1 / 6, '#ff0' );
gradientC.addColorStop ( 2 / 6, '#0f0' );
gradientC.addColorStop ( 3 / 6, '#0ff' );
gradientC.addColorStop ( 4 / 6, '#00f' );
gradientC.addColorStop ( 5 / 6, '#f0f' );
gradientC.addColorStop ( 1, '#f00' );

drawColorRef.fillStyle = gradientC;
drawColorRef.fillRect ( 0, 0, drawColorRef.canvas.width, drawColorRef.canvas.height );
```

```css
.slider {
  width: 3px;
  height: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 7px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="firstColorSlider" width="300px" height="12px"></canvas>
<div class="slider"></div>
```

My question is:
For example, we can type the hex code in the HTML color input, and the color slider will be positioned at the appropriate position, and the color board would be updated, then the marker would mark where the color is at.

Take `#0acb57` for experiment:

1. How do I know where the slider`.slider` should be on the slider canvas`#firstColorSlider` so it would update the board which has the experiment color.
2. Then how to know the position where `#0acb57` is at on the board?

Reference: I create the color board by following this tutorial: https://dev.to/bhaskar95460442/create-an-html-color-picker-using-javascript-3obm

Here is the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/5d183sqg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert the RGB (red-green-blue) color to HSL (hue-saturation-light).
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV
After you get the HSL components, then:

- hue is on the vertical slider
- saturation is the x-coordinate on the square canvas
- light is the y-coordinate on the square canvas

Comment: Hi, the 'hue is on the vertical slider' seems correct. But I don't understand the other two. The HSL for the experiement color `#0acb57` is `144, 91%, 42%`. how to calculate 91% as the x-coordinate and 42% for the y-coordinate? FYI, I calculate the hue by `hue / 360 * 300`.

Comment: I found that HSV is working instead of HSL, thanks for the inspiration anyway.